# Qt 5.12 TextArea focus is lost forever

Tags: qt, qml

When TextArea is a child of ApplicationWindow with flag set to Qt.Popup, it is not possible to set focus neither by mouse clicking not by calling forceActiveFocus(). Here is the code :

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.5
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.3

ApplicationWindow {
    id : mainWin
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Bug reproduction scenario")

    Material.theme: Material.Dark

    TextArea {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        placeholderText: qsTr("parent text")
    }

    Button {
        id : closeAppBtn
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        text : qsTr("Close app")

        onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }
    }

    ApplicationWindow {
        id : childWin
        width : mainWin.width/2
        height: mainWin.height/2
        visible: false

        Material.theme: Material.Dark

        x : mainWin.x + width/4
        y : mainWin.y + height/4

        flags : Qt.Popup

        TextArea {
            id : childTextArea
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            placeholderText: qsTr("child text")
        }

        Button {
            id : closeParentWinBtn
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            text : qsTr("Close child win")

            onClicked: {
                childWin.close();
            }
        }

    }

    Button {
        text : qsTr("show another window")
        anchors.left : closeAppBtn.right
        anchors.leftMargin: closeAppBtn.width/2
        anchors.top : closeAppBtn.top
        onClicked: {
            if ( !childWin.visible ) {
                childWin.visible = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's not possible to set focus to `childTextArea` neither by mouse clicking nor by setting forceActiveFocus().

The same component is placed on the first window and it's ok to set focus to it. And if you comment out setting flag to Qt.Popup evertyhing is ok.

Is it a known behaviour? What should I do to use TextArea inside ApplicationWindow with PopUp flag?

Comment: Put `qputenv("QSG_VISUALIZE", "overdraw");` at the beginning of your `int main()...` function and see if it is a z-index issue.

Comment: I've put this line but I'm not sure how to interpret it. I see a 3D box with 2 red places placed in parallel.

Comment: Oh ok. It just helps you understand how your elements are overlayed.  If you have lots of nested or overlapping elements, that trick shows you what's going on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this tip. Are you able to try my code? Would you see the same issue?

Comment: It worked for me. I had to use `import QtQuick 2.11
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4` because of my version.

Comment: Great, so it seems the issue is related to versioning. Did you check it under Linux? And what is your exact Qt version, 5.11?

Comment: I was on Windows 10, Qt 5.11.2 and those versions of QtQuick et c.

Comment: Just curious, why do you need child `ApplicationWindow` with Popup flag?

Comment: Hm, nothing special here, originally I wanted a separate window, so ApplicationWindow is fine and then I started playing with flags property for styling only and found this issue.